# How can I use DBAN on a dual-boot machine?

Tags: multi-boot, grub, dban

I have a dual-boot machine Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and I wish to remove both using DBAN and try another OS.

The thing is, how do I do that?

Do I just plug in DBAN and everything will go away?

Or will the GRUB boot loader interfere with the process?

Comment: Have you read this resource https://dban.org/ and https://tiptopsecurity.com/how-to-securely-wipe-your-hard-drive-with-dban-erase-your-data-for-good/

Comment: I've used it by booting a thumb-drive, compact-flash card, and it just wiped all disks installed on the machine. How you boot it is up to you, and what media you install it to (also likely how you grab it).  However I don't see that as Ubuntu related and thus on-topic for this site (as it's Ubuntu you want to remove; not use). https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

DBAN doesn't care about grub. It nukes everything on the hard drive including grub. The Ubuntu installer has an "Erase *the-existing-OS* and install Ubuntu" feature, so you don't need to run DBAN first if you're planning to install Ubuntu over either Windows 10 or Ubuntu. In fact you don't need to run DBAN at all. The Ubuntu live USB includes GParted which can be run from the live USB to quick reformat a partition or an entire hard drive. Quick reformatting a partition with GParted takes only a few seconds. This will safely and quickly prepare the hard drive for any OS to be installed on it, including Windows if the hard drive is reformatted as ntfs. Using DBAN is overkill for this task.

Comment: +1; and a comment: You may want to wipe the whole drive, if you intend to sell or give the computer to someone else. In that case DBAN can be a good alternative for a hard disk drive. But I would use another method for an SSD, that is connected *via SATA*. There is usually a built-in tool in the SSD (and HDD), that can be activated via `hdparm`. It will re-arrange the mapping between logical and physical addresses so that there will be no way to read the old content. This is fast and does not wear the memory cells. Please avoid the method when connected via USB, it may destroy the drive.